# Writing to socket fails after X bytes

Tags: java, sockets

I'm attempting to write song data to a socket however after approximately 66338 bytes the following exception is thrown:

```
    E/        ( 1016): Connection reset by peer
    E/        ( 1016): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    E/        ( 1016):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.writeSocketImpl(Native Method)
    E/        ( 1016):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.write(OSNetworkSystem.java:723)
    E/        ( 1016):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:578)
    E/        ( 1016):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:59)
    E/        ( 1016):  at com.myprogram.StreamProxy.processRequest(StreamProxy.java:307)
    E/        ( 1016):  at com.myprogram.StreamProxy.run(StreamProxy.java:145)
    E/        ( 1016):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

This only happens with certain songs and if one song does it all of the songs in the entire album do the same thing.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the header information for the song?

Any suggestions on how to debug or fix this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT:  Here's the code that is reading from an InputStream and writing back out to a socket.  The code is pretty straight forward so I'm not really sure why it would be crashing unless the connection is being closed on the receiving end.  (Note: this is only psuedocode, but gives the general idea)

```
    InputStream data = realResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    Socket socket = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {127,0,0,1}));
    socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
    port = socket.getLocalPort();
    Socket client = socket.accept();

    ...some code...

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 50];
    while (isRunning && (readBytes = data.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
      client.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, readBytes);
    }
```

Also, could this have anything to do with the socket buffer filling up? Especially since it seems to crash at 64k every time.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?  You're much more likely to get helped that way.

Comment: I've posted some pseudocode to give a better idea of what is happening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server process on the other side likely had an abnormal termination (ex. SIGKILL).  That would cause a connection rest.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says that the peer (server or client) closed the connection, to me it could be that you're reading (parsing) wrong the server's response on the client or vice versa.

Comment: Since it's a connection reset it would most likely imply something croaked badly (process died) rather than a simple connection close or mishandling the wire protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the bug is in your code. If you could attach the code it will be helpful to narrow down the error. If you feel it has something to do with header use wireshark to see when that happens.

EDIT: I feel it has something to do with setSoTimeout(milliseconds) this will timeout after 5 seconds of inactivity as you have written in the code. This i guess should be the reason for the following statement of yours "if one song does it all of the songs in the entire album do the same thing".

Try increasing the timeout value.

Comment: I set the timeout to 0 so there is no timeout.  However, I am still getting the same error.